# Flask redirect setting cookie in incorrect location

Tags: python, nginx, redirect, flask, cookies

Currently working on an SSO service that redirects upon a successful login. It is a Flask app run behind Nginx. After the dealing with the SSO providers and verifying important information, I would like to redirect the user to a different site and store a cookie associated with that site. For example, if the SSO server is https://sso.com, I would like to redirect to https://example.com and store the cookie there. However, at the moment it is storing the cookie at https://sso.com instead.

I have not dealt with cookies before so sorry I misuse terminology.

I initially expected that it was an Nginx issue, but the behavior is the same even when I run the app locally, when it is not using Nginx. Tried a number of Set-Cookie arguments like SameSite, Domain, etc but could not get it to work. Everytime the cookie is set in https://sso.com.

The more I think about it, the less I'm convinced this desired behavior is even possible. Wouldn't setting a cookie on a different site open up security vulnerabilities? If so, what would a better system be?

Thanks!

```py
@auth.route('/test/cookie', methods=['GET'], strict_slashes=False)
def test_cookie():
    redirectUrl = request.headers.get('redirect', None)
    if redirectUrl is None:
        resp = make_response(jsonify({'status_message': 'SUCCESS', 'message': 'stuff'}), 200)
        resp.set_cookie("cow", "moo")
        return resp
    else:
        resp = make_response(redirect(redirectUrl))
        resp.set_cookie("dog", "woof", samesite=None)
        return resp
```